# Converting "bad" characters to their equivalent without a direct string.Replace and a list

Tags: c#

I have done my research and everything I've found either does nothing or is too Leeroy Jenkins and replaces everything else that it shouldn't. It's possible that I'm phrasing everything wrong in my search and so coming up with nothing.

I have to replace all the wrong characters that rich text programs (and older programs) autocorrect for the user because the user then copy/pasts directly into a web form.

For example, the "funky" apostrophe (`’`) converted to the regular apostrophe (`'`) and the quotation marks and everything else.

I've tried UTF en/decoding, diacritic removal (not at all what I need), and a direct brute force string.Replace isn't reasonable, really.

Here's some example text that has all the bad stuff:

```
"They’re taking the hobbits to Isengaurd with bad apostrophe’s instead of good one's. Itâ€™s just how they roll."
```

Note that the only good apostrophe is in `one's` and already have one rendered result of this (`Itâ€™s`) so I need to convert it back (along with all the other baddies) without a string.Replace and a list of characters to watch for.

What ought I be doing here?

To clarify: I need to convert the bad characters to good equivalents before data is submitted AND I need to catch existing stuff that was rendered after it was saved. So I need to do two things here.

Comment: Your string is already encoded, and changing the encoding would result in a different string. It's not possible to change `â€™` to `'` without a lookup table

Comment: What is the problem with solutions you've tried so far? It sounds like you have code that replaces characters but doesn't do what you want. If that's the case, please share the code.

Comment: As indicated, the remove diacritics code works on diacritics but not, for example, the punctuation. That's posted elsewhere on SO so I'm not posting it here. Everything else I've tried doesn't actually do anything but isn't non-functional so isn't related to the problem. There's just no code to post that's related to the problem I'm having unless you want me to post a bunch of string.replace lines.

Comment: What exactly is a "bad char"? Is there a (positive or negative) list?